# Javascript: get the parent's prototype `this`

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I work on improving some bezier easing functions and have a problem with `this`. Basically, an `Ease` object.

```
Ease.bezier = function(mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2) {
    return _bezier.processBezier(mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2);
};

var _bezier = Ease.bezier.prototype;

_bezier.processBezier = function (mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2) {

    console.log(this) // this shows the proper object       
    this.mX1 = mX1;
    this.mX2 = mX2;
    this.mY1 = mY1;
    this.mY2 = mY2;

   return _bezier.render;      
};

_bezier.render = function(aX){ 
    console.log(this) // this shows another object
    if (this.mX1 === this.mY1 && this.mX2 === this.mY2) return aX;

    if (aX === 0) return 0;
    if (aX === 1) return 1; 
    return _bezier.computeBezier(_bezier.gx(aX), this.mY1, this.mY2);       
};
```

The `_bezier.render` function is the one that's bound to a tweening engine, like [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js), and thus inherits it's `this`, so the values for `this.mX1` and other bezier related values are undefined in the `_bezier.render` function.

If I replace `this` with `_bezier`, animation works but will always use the last instance's values for all the other animations.

So, the question is, is there a way to get `this` from `_bezier.processBezier` inside the `_bezier.render` function somehow?

Or perhaps I can simplify the code by binding functions in a way to access the right `this`?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I am don't understand your code. Why you use _bezier befor create it?  Ease.bezier = function(mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2) {
    return _bezier.processBezier(mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2);
};

Comment: I think you don't understand oop and javascript prototype way.

Comment: Why not use "this" inside of functions, instead of _bezier?

Comment: As I said, `this` is no longer the `Ease` object, it's another object.

Comment: Please show us how `render` is "*bound to a tweening engine like tween.js*". Probably you can simply use `.bind` before passing it in there.

Comment: I really wonder why you are using a `.prototype` when your `Ease.bezier` "constructor" does return a function, and no instance whatsoever.

Comment: @Bergi this is where the easing function is bound to the tweening engine
https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/src/Tween.js#L310

Comment: @thednp: I don't see any binding there. It's just a normal function call.

Comment: So why my console.log shows the tween object instead of ease object?

Comment: Maybe because you confuse the tween object with the global object. But regardless, if you bind it to the instance as demonstrated below (and `processBezier` is actually called on the instance, of course), then your log will show the ease object.

Comment: @Bergi. Thanks for your replies, I feel you should have been the one who I should have marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use .bind() method to get the right 'this':

```
// ...
_bezier.processBezier = function (mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2) {

    console.log(this) // this shows the proper object
    this.mX1 = mX1;
    this.mX2 = mX2;
    this.mY1 = mY1;
    this.mY2 = mY2;

    // use .bind(this)
    return _bezier.render.bind(this);
};
// ...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, unfortunately, it seems that this bind produces the same result as using `_bezier` instead of `this` inside the `render` function.

Comment: @thednp: That's because your call `_bezier.processBezier(…)` is wrong and `this === _bezier` (which you surely don't want).

Comment: @Bergi I think I better incorporate the `Ease` object inside the TWEEN.Tween prototype, so I have the exact `this` that I need in the entire `Ease` object.

Comment: @thednp: Do whatever you want as long as you understand how it works :-)

Comment: @Bergi, sorry, quick question: can I use `.bind` to link the `Ease` and `Tween` objects? This way I may have the exact `this` I need inside the entire `Ease` object.

Comment: @thednp: Yes, you can, just as described in this answer, if only you would properly construct `Ease` instances

Comment: Alright, marked as answered, I will rewrite the code so that it works in this fashion.

Comment: @Bergi, I added another question related to this, I came with an idea on how to do it, I think you must have a solution for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575005/javascript-pass-function-arguments-into-another-function-via-bind