# Pass function arguments into another function via `bind`

Tags: javascript, arguments, bind

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569200/javascript-get-the-parents-prototype-this/31569864), so I'll add almost same code as example here.

```
Ease.bezier = function(mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2) {
    return _bezier.processBezier(mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2);
};

var _bezier = Ease.bezier.prototype;

_bezier.processBezier = function (mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2) {
   return _bezier.render; // this is where I need the `this`, mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2 to be passed into the next function
};

_bezier.render = function(aX){ //the aX value here comes from another object
    var mX1 = [bound function attributes[1]]; // I think you can understand what I mean here
    if (mX1 === mY1 && mX2 === mY2) return aX;

    if (aX === 0) return 0;
    if (aX === 1) return 1; 
    return _bezier.computeBezier(_bezier.gx(aX), mY1, mY2);     
};
```

Now I need to know if I can bind the two functions somehow without affecting the `aX` value coming from another object and having access to the `this`, and `mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2` arguments into the second function.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: What `processBezier` supposed to return?

Comment: The result of the `render` function, a number that's in the bezier graph with progression and time axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "and having access to `this`"? Isn't this *exactly* what was answered in your previous question?

Comment: There isn't enough information here. What is the `.gx()` method? What does the `computeBezier()` method look like? What would be some sample code that *uses* this class? One tip though: the places where you use `_bezier` *inside* the methods should probably all be `this` instead, because you want to refer to the current instance of your object, not just the bare function on the prototype.

Comment: @Bergi I realized I should have known about `bind` before asking the previous question, this is actually what I needed, and the one who answered below gave an excellent answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object like this ??

```
_bezier.processBezier = function (mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2) {
  return _bezier.render.bind(this, arguments); // <--- bind all the arguments and the context "this"
};

_bezier.render = function(){ // <--- aX is not required anymore instead use arguments object
  var args = arguments[0]; // <--- this corresponds to [mX1, mY1, mX2, mY2]
  var aX = arguments[1]; // <--- this corresponds to aX now
  if (args[0] === args[1] && args[2] === args[3]) return aX; // <--- notice args object here

  if (aX === 0) return 0;
  if (aX === 1) return 1; 
  return _bezier.computeBezier(_bezier.gx(aX), mY1, mY2);     
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the console log shows great. Wonderful answer.

Comment: And I confirm, your answer worked. Well deserved points, I wish I could reward with more reputation points :)

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: Another quick question. Is there a faster way to achieve this? I've read some stuff that a closure can be twice faster than `bind`, do you have any idea how is that?